# Efficiently joining more than 2 data.tables

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I was wondering if there is a memory efficient way to join n data.tables (or data frames). For example, if I have the following 4 data.tables:

```
df1 = data.table(group = c(1L,2L,3L),value = rnorm(3),key = "group")
df2 = data.table(group = c(2L,1L,3L),value2 = rnorm(3),key = "group")
df3 = data.table(group = c(3L,2L,1L),value3 = rnorm(3),key = "group")
df4 = data.table(group = c(1L,3L,2L),value4 = rnorm(3),key = "group")
```

I could merge them like so:

```
merge(df1,merge(df2,merge(df3,df4)))
```

but that does not seem like an optimal solution. I might potentially have many data.tables that need to be merged. Is there a way to generalize the above without copying each successive merge to memory? Is there an already accepted way outside of data.table to do this?

Comment: One solution is to put all of the data frames in a list, then use `Reduce()` to merge them. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list

Comment: `Reduce(function(x, y) x[y], list(df1, df2, df3, df4))` seems to be a little faster on the data you provided, but you would have to test this out on larger inputs to see how it scales.

Comment: @ulfelder That's just semantic sugar.  The same merge operations will take place.

Comment: It depends on your actual application. If your merging variables match up exactly in all tables, as here, then just copy the cols over

Comment: @Frank, you're right, though in my actual application there's very large discrepancies. I probably should have demonstrated that in the example.

Comment: @BoudewijnAasman Perhaps my edit helps.

Comment: I guess there are many questions you'd have to consider. The re-arranging Matthew did isn't a real problem on its own -- just `setorder` before copying over. If you know that each `group` value appears in at most one row, then you can just make the final table (with one row per group) and then do a bunch of merge-assigns. If you know that each table just has a single extra column (patterned `value*` as here) then you can `rbindlist` them and then reshape... I guess there are other cases as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some other options you may have, depending on your data. Other options apart from the obvious path of doing a ton of merges, I mean: in a loop, with `Reduce` or with hadley's `join_all`/`merge_all`/`wrap_em_all_up`.

These are all methods that I have used and found to be faster in my own work, but I don't intend to attempt a general benchmarking case. First, some setup:

```
DFlist = list(df1,df2,df3,df4)
bycols = key(DFlist[[1]])
```

I'll assume the tables are all keyed by the `bycols`.

**Stack.** If the new cols from each table are somehow related to each other and appear in the same positions in every table, then consider just stacking the data:

```
DFlong = rbindlist(DFlist, use.names = FALSE, idcol = TRUE)
```

If for some reason you really want the data in wide format, you can `dcast`:

```
dcast(DFlong, 
  formula = sprintf("%s ~ .id", paste(bycols, collapse = "+")), 
  value.var = setdiff(names(DFlong), c(bycols, ".id"))
)
```

Data.table and R work best with long-format data, though.

**Copy cols.** If you know that the `bycols` take all the same values in all of the tables, then just copy over:

```
DF = DFlist[[1]][, bycols, with=FALSE]
for (k in seq_along(DFlist)){
  newcols = setdiff(names(DFlist[[k]]), bycols)
  DF[, (newcols) := DFlist[[k]][, newcols, with=FALSE]]
}
```

**Merge assign.** If some levels of `bycols` may be missing from certain tables, then make a master table with all combos and do a sequence of merge-assigns:

```
DF = unique(rbindlist(lapply(DFlist, `[`, j = bycols, with = FALSE)))
for (k in seq_along(DFlist)){
  newcols = setdiff(names(DFlist[[k]]), bycols)
  DF[DFlist[[k]], (newcols) := mget(newcols)]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In dplyr:

As your trials all have the same names (and you have scrubbed out the NA's) you can just bind on the rows and summarise.

```
library(dplyr)

DF <- bind_rows(df1,df2,df3,df4) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(na.omit))
```

Otherwise there is the simple, local minima solution: though at least coding in this dialect saves shaving a few layers off your own onion.

```
DF <- 
    df1 %>% 
    full_join(df2) %>% 
    full_join(df3) %>% 
    full_join(df4)
```

As dplyr runs in C++ not S, it should be faster. I unfortunately am unable to speak to the efficiency of memory usage.

(for similar situations see: [*R: Updating a data frame with another data frame*'s dplyr sol'n](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37313185/5088194))

Comment: If some cols have legit NAs, the first approach might get weird.

Comment: I am testing how it responds to NA's and (un)fortunately am not finding any problems. `df3 = data.table(group = c(3L,2L),value3 = rnorm(2),key = "group")`

Comment: By NAs, I mean NAs :) Try `df3 = data.table(group = c(NA,2L,1L),value3 = rnorm(3),key = "group")` or with `df3 = data.table(group = c(3L,2L,1L),value3 = rnorm(3),key = "group")[2, value3 := NA]`. Both of these lead to an error with your first approach on my computer.

Comment: Hmm. True: `Error: expecting a single value` At least it doesn't return incorrect values. Will add caveat above.