# update value based on another df in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

How can I update a value of a df based on another df, changing the old values that are not present in the new df? I have df1 (old) and df2 (update), and would like to produce the Desired outcome.

df1 (old)

| ID | iso_pres |
| --- | --- |
| 1504a | 1 |
| 1504b | 1 |
| 1504c | 1 |
| 1705a | 1 |
| 1705b | 1 |

df2 (update)

| ID | iso_pres |
| --- | --- |
| 1504b | 1 |
| 1705a | 1 |
| 1705b | 1 |

Desired outcome

| ID | iso_pres |
| --- | --- |
| 1504a | 0 |
| 1504b | 1 |
| 1504c | 0 |
| 1705a | 1 |
| 1705b | 1 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: Updating a data frame with another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312659/r-updating-a-data-frame-with-another-data-frame)

Comment: using these command I can't update the values of the old df, just include new values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%in%` function to check for boolean match and replace the false with 0 in Base R.

```
old <- data.frame(ID = c(paste0(1504, letters[1:3]), "1705a", "1705b"), iso_press = 1)

df2 <- old[c(2,4,5),]

old$iso_press <- ifelse(old$ID %in% df2$ID, old$iso_press, 0)
```

or in dplyr:

```
old |> 
  mutate(iso_press = ifelse(ID %in% df2$ID, iso_press, 0 ))
```

```
     ID iso_press
1 1504a         0
2 1504b         1
3 1504c         0
4 1705a         1
5 1705b         1
```